# Mathematics involved in "Jabberwocky"

Tags: logic

The famous poem, "Jabberwocky" by Lewis Carroll contains a plethora of weird words.

However, Carroll is known as a celebrated mathematician and logician.

Does "Jabberwocky" have any mathematics in it?

Comment: "One, two! One, two!" What could be more mathematical?

Comment: You seem to have not read Keith Devlin's article https://www.maa.org/external_archive/devlin/devlin_03_10.html

Comment: I would not call Lewis Carroll a **celebrated** mathematician or logician. He did make some contributions to both fields, but nothing long-lasting.

Comment: @FirdousAhmadMala You are right: I have not read that article.  But I did read the poem, including its line 17.  Which refers to mathematical objects.

Comment: Some associations with mathematical linguistics and computational biology are discussed in [Searls, From Jabberwocky to Genome](https://www.liebertpub.com/doi/10.1089/10665270152530881).

Comment: @FirdousAhmadMala Keith Devlin's article does point out several mathematical points in the Alice books, but not specifically in Jabberwocky. "One, two, one , two" cannot really be counted (LOL) as "mathematics, can it ?

Comment: The next math object I introduce will be called jubberwock.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that Jubberwocky has been translated into other languages together with the whole book. For example, in Russian it is called "Бармаглот", and starts with 

Варкалось. Хливкие шорьки
Пырялись по наве,
И хрюкотали зелюки,
Как мюмзики в мове.

Comment: @MoisheKohan One long-lasting mathematical contribution that he made was Dodgson condensation. See for example Francine Abeles's article, [Dodgson condensation: The historical and mathematical development of an experimental method](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2007.11.022).

Comment: @TimothyChow: Interesting, I did not know about this one (even though, I knew about the alternating sign matrices conjecture). One sentence in the link I find astounding "In 1995 Zeilberger’s proof of the ASM conjecture was accepted by the 88 referees."

Answer (score 1):

Another source is:

> Martin Gardner, *The Annotated Alice*

with extensive commentary on both Alice books.

[image]

Comment: Does Gardner identify any mathematics in *Jabberwocky*?